# Función dentro de otra ventana

Tags: python, tkinter, numpy

*CODIGO COMPLETO*

Aquí está el código completo, no sé si me habré equivocado en algunas cosas, si es así me corrigen porfavor. Estoy haciendo un menú de 4 opciones, esta es la primera opción:

```
import numpy
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
ventas = numpy.array ( [ [ [ 24,45,44,40,37,70,80 ] ,
                           [ 33,45,32,55,46,75,90 ] ,
                           [ 45,40,37,38,40,80,85 ] ] ,
                         [ [ 40,41,38,42,38,90,75 ] ,
                           [ 39,39,42,40,42,88,98 ] ,
                           [ 41,41,44,36,38,98,90 ] ] ,
                         [ [ 24,45,44,40,37,95,82 ] ,
                           [ 33,45,32,55,46,97,98 ] ,
                           [ 45,40,37,38,40,98,98 ] ] ,
                         [ [ 40,41,38,42,38,90,50 ] ,
                           [ 39,39,42,40,42,80,78 ] ,
                           [ 41,41,44,36,38,50,70 ] ] ] )
vendedores = numpy.array([ " Juan Perez " , " María Acuña " , " Pedro Fuentes " ] )

def sacar_promedio():
    total=[]
    tra=ventas[semana.get()-1,trabajador.get()-1]
    total.append(tra)
    if semana.get() ==  1:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))
    elif semana.get() == 2:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))
    elif semana.get() == 3:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))
    else:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))  
    mensaje.set("El promedio semanal del trabajador es: "+ str(round(total2)))**texto en negrita**
    mensaje2.set("El total semanal del trabajador es: "+str(round(total1)))**texto en negrita**
    win = Tk()
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.title("La Favorita")
    win.geometry('800x300')
    win.config(bg="dark turquoise")
    e5 = tk.Label(win, text="Resultado final")
    e5.pack(side=tk.TOP)
    etiquetaa = Label(win, textvariable=mensaje).place(x=100, y=150)
    etiquetaa2 = Label(win, textvariable=mensaje2).place(x=100, y=200)
    

    
ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("La Favorita")
ventana.config(bg="dark turquoise")
ventana.geometry('800x500')
etiqueta1= Button(ventana, text="1-total semanal vendido y promedio semanal del trabajador", command=sacar_promedio).place(x=30, y=0)** aqui quiero que me calcule todo**
semana = IntVar()
trabajador = IntVar()
mensaje = StringVar()
mensaje2 = StringVar()
etiqueta = Label(ventana, text="Selecciona una semana").place(x=20, y=150)
ola = Spinbox(ventana, from_=1, to=4, textvariable=semana).place(x=300, y=150)
boton2 = Button(ventana, text="resultado", command=sacar_promedio).place(x=100, y=250)
etiquetaL = Label(ventana, text="Seleccione trabajador:").place(x=20, y=200)
ola2 = Spinbox(ventana, from_=1, to=3, textvariable=trabajador).place(x=300, y=200)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Quiero poner esta ventana dentro de otra ventana con un 'Button' que me arroje el resultado del trabajador y semana que quiero, no sé muy bien, acepto consejos, gracias.

Lo probé y corre bien, pero igual sale una ventanita chica que no sé que es, si me pudieran orientar se los agradeceria.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. No es muy claro lo que solicitas en la pregunta. ¿Cuál es el problema puntual? ¿Qué error o motivo te impide lograr lo que solicitas?

Comment: quiero crear un boton que me llame a la funcion y me deje elegir entre semanas y trabajadores y alfinal me arroje el resultado

Comment: Y ¿Qué error te impide hacerlo?

Comment: me sale la funcion en la ventana principal cuando quiero que me salga al apretar el boton, entonces no se como hacer para que solo se muestre cuando presione el boton y muestre el resultado

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La ventanita extra te sale porque estás creando una nueva ventana principal con:

```
win = Tk()
```

Para crear sub-ventanas debes utilizar `Toplevel` tal como lo haces en la línea siguiente a la línea errónea antes mencionada.

Al comentar/eliminar la línea erronea tu programa funciona correctamente.

### Información adicional:

Al importar un paquete es recomendable no importar todo el contenido de esta forma:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Ya que si hubiera funciones con el mismo nombre que alguna función estandar de `Python` o de otro módulo que estuvieramos utilizando entonces se utilizaría el de la última librería importada. Es mejor importar los módulos y asignarles un alias, de la siguiente forma:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Ahora, no comprendo el motivo por el que hayas puesto las siguientes 3 líneas:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
```

Primero estás importando todos los componentes de `tkinter` luego importas `tkinter otra vez pero le das un alias y por último importas únicamente` messagebox`de`tkinter`. La línea de enmedio sería la única que necesitas y por lo tanto todos los elementos de` tkinter`deberían iniciar con`tk.`

Por ejemplo, en lugar de:

```
ventana = Tk()
```

Sería

```
ventana = tk.Tk()
```

Por último, los comentarios en `Python` se inician con la almoadilla (`#`), no con asterisco, eso hizo que tu ejemplo no se ejecutara y aparecieran errores al intentar solucionar tu problema.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import numpy
import tkinter as tk

ventas = numpy.array ( [ [ [ 24,45,44,40,37,70,80 ] ,
                           [ 33,45,32,55,46,75,90 ] ,
                           [ 45,40,37,38,40,80,85 ] ] ,
                         [ [ 40,41,38,42,38,90,75 ] ,
                           [ 39,39,42,40,42,88,98 ] ,
                           [ 41,41,44,36,38,98,90 ] ] ,
                         [ [ 24,45,44,40,37,95,82 ] ,
                           [ 33,45,32,55,46,97,98 ] ,
                           [ 45,40,37,38,40,98,98 ] ] ,
                         [ [ 40,41,38,42,38,90,50 ] ,
                           [ 39,39,42,40,42,80,78 ] ,
                           [ 41,41,44,36,38,50,70 ] ] ] )
vendedores = numpy.array([ " Juan Perez " , " María Acuña " , " Pedro Fuentes " ] )

def sacar_promedio():
    total=[]
    tra=ventas[semana.get()-1,trabajador.get()-1]
    total.append(tra)
    if semana.get() ==  1:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))
    elif semana.get() == 2:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))
    elif semana.get() == 3:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))
    else:
        total1 = ((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))
        total2 = ((((numpy.sum(numpy.array(total)*1000)))/7))  
    mensaje.set("El promedio semanal del trabajador es: "+ str(round(total2)))
    mensaje2.set("El total semanal del trabajador es: "+str(round(total1)))
    
    # Esta línea sobra
    #win = Tk()
    
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.title("La Favorita")
    win.geometry('800x300')
    win.config(bg="dark turquoise")
    e5 = tk.Label(win, text="Resultado final")
    e5.pack(side=tk.TOP)
    etiquetaa = tk.Label(win, textvariable=mensaje).place(x=100, y=150)
    etiquetaa2 = tk.Label(win, textvariable=mensaje2).place(x=100, y=200)
    
    
ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("La Favorita")
ventana.config(bg="dark turquoise")
ventana.geometry('800x500')
etiqueta1= tk.Button(ventana, text="1-total semanal vendido y promedio semanal del trabajador", command=sacar_promedio).place(x=30, y=0)#** aqui quiero que me calcule todo**
semana = tk.IntVar()
trabajador = tk.IntVar()
mensaje = tk.StringVar()
mensaje2 = tk.StringVar()
etiqueta = tk.Label(ventana, text="Selecciona una semana").place(x=20, y=150)
ola = tk.Spinbox(ventana, from_=1, to=4, textvariable=semana).place(x=300, y=150)
boton2 = tk.Button(ventana, text="resultado", command=sacar_promedio).place(x=100, y=250)
etiquetaL = tk.Label(ventana, text="Seleccione trabajador:").place(x=20, y=200)
ola2 = tk.Spinbox(ventana, from_=1, to=3, textvariable=trabajador).place(x=300, y=200)
ventana.mainloop()
```